# How to trim a percentage of data points within a specific range in R

Tags: r, random, bioinformatics

I have a text file containing millions of p-values (Range: 1 - 5e-09, ($P)). My goal is to generate a Manhattan plot in R using these p-values. However, since the vast majority of the p-values are in the 0.01-1 range, I would like to randomly trim say, 95% of the p-values in this range before generating the plot (so as to reduce the output file size). Until now, I have been using:

```
data <- read.table(<path_to_my_p-value_file>)
data <- subset(data,data$P<=0.01)
```

but this command removes **all** p-values greater than 0.01, which results in an unsightly gap between the x-axis and the remaining p-values in the Manhattan plot. Is there a way to trim **most** of the p-values within a specified range (instead of all)?

Comment: (1) When using `subset(data, ...)`, there is no reason to use `data$` within the call, just use `subset(data, P <= 0.01)`. This is not true of all functions, but `subset` and all `dplyr::` functions appreciate "non-standard evaluation". (2) It would be much easier if you could generate a reasonable sample dataset (it doesn't have to be actual p-values) to demonstrate what you start with and what you intend. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a method that would zero out 90% of the highest 95% of values. Obviously you would not want to be doing this on an original of your data, but rather on a copy from which you would then remove the 0's. Multiply the higher p-values (highest 95% in this example)  by a random sampling from {,0,1} that is of the correct length with a probability of 0.9 for the 0 and 0.1 for the 1

```
 set.seed(123)
 dx <- data.frame(x=runif(100))
 dx$sel <- dx$x < 0.05    #Should "select" the lowest 5%, leave them alone
 dx$x[!dx$sel] <- dx$x[!dx$sel]*   # only work on the higher ones
                       sample(c(0,1),size=sum(!dx$sel), replace=TRUE, prob=c(.9,.1))
```

Gets you five values below 0.05 and 11 above 0.05. The exact number of those higher values will vary a bit depending on the random seed and the length of the constructed vector.

```
> table(dx$x)

                   0 0.000624773325398564   0.0246136845089495   0.0420595335308462 
                  84                    1                    1                    1 
  0.0455564993899316   0.0458311666734517   0.0935949867125601    0.102924682665616 
                   1                    1                    1                    1 
   0.320373242488131    0.414546335814521    0.453334156190977    0.511505459900945 
                   1                    1                    1                    1 
    0.59414202044718    0.656758127966896    0.883017404004931    0.892419044394046 
                   1                    1                    1                    1 
   0.954503649147227
```

You also might look at the code used by functions that do "winsorizing". (No, I didn't misspell that term.)

Answer (score 2):

It feels a bit hacky, but the following could do it. Basically it checks first for a condition (here if x > 0) and then replaces to missing a percentage of the values based on `runif()` (here .95). After that you could remove the rows with missing values.

There should be a better way of achieving the desired results though...

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(
  x = if_else(condition = x > 0,
              true = if_else(runif(length(x))<.95, NA_real_, x),
              false = x
  )
)
```

#### reprex

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
n <- 300
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(n), 
  y = rnorm(n)
)

df2 <- df %>% mutate(
  x = if_else(condition = x > 0,
              true = if_else(runif(length(x))<.95, NA_real_, x),
              false = x
  )
)
plot(df, pch = 3)
points(df2, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>